# What is the closed form of infinite sum $x+x^4+x^7+x^{10}+...$?

Tags: calculus

I know that $1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$, $1+x^2+x^4+...=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$. It seems to follow some rules of geometric series. But I'm confused how to get the title from here. Thanks

Comment: It's a geometric series with ratio $x^3$

Comment: So ... try $x^3$ in place of $x^2$?

Comment: Change $x$ to $x^{3}$ in you first equation and multiply both sides by $x$.

Comment: Try $x (1+x^3+x^6+\cdots)$. Note that the series converges only if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always nice, if we want to see if the sum is geometric, to do factoring to ensure that the first term of the sum is $1$, so factor out an $x$:

$$x + x^4 + x^7 + x^{10} + ... = x(1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 + ...)$$

The parenthetical expression is a geometric series in which the ratio is $x^3$. Then as a result, by the formula for an infinite geometric sum,

$$1 + x^3 + x^6 + x^9 + ... = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$

Thus, bringing in the factored-out $x$,

$$x + x^4 + x^7 + x^{10} + ... = \frac{x}{1-x^3}$$

Note that the formula for a geometric sum only holds when the ratio is less than $1$ in magnitude. Thus we require $|x^3| < 1$. (This can be simplified to $|x| < 1$ as $|x^n|=|x|^n$ and then you just take the cube root.)